# Can I cast multiple copies of Bless at a time?

Tags: spells, middle-earth-role-playing

I play a level 2 ranger in MERP and I am in the possession of a +2 spell adder. I was thinking about taking the protection spell list and I was wondering if I could somehow stack multiple castings of  Bless to give me a larger bonus to DB. I do know that you can only cast one spell per round but could I for example cast one and pay a power point for it this round and than cast it again next round and pay another power point and have +20 to DB?

Comment: **Note to potential answerers**: Real answers will be based on knowing MERP, and will not just assume that D&D's “no stacking” rule exists in MERP. We have already deleted a number of posts of that type. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in ***MERP*** that explictly clarifies what happens if you cast the same spell twice.

If a character were to cast a spell twice (such as Bless) there are two obvious things that can happen.

1. The spells duration is extended to end according to when the second spell was cast.
2. The spells effects stack for the duration of when both spells are active.

Neither the duration, area of effect or any other spell section (principally in section 7.1 spell lists, p.56) clarify which of these two should be chosen, therefore it's really a GM call and I've just reread it all just to make sure I didn't miss anything!

However.

MERP is the baby of ***Rolemaster*** (It's a simplified single book version of it) which has somewhat more detailed rules for spells. It's still rather lacking in some areas - hence my supplimentary 100+ page folder of house rule clarifications!

ICE 1200 Spell Law ('Classic Rolemaster') has some more useful info on page 34, especially the section 'combining spell effects'

> The effects of spells of the same name cannot normally be combined
>   (e.g. the effects of a *Protection I* and a *Protection II* spell
>   cannot be combined.) The various *Aura* spells may not be combined
>   with *Blur.*.  A Gamemaster may not want to allow certain other spells
>   to be combined. If it is more appropriate in his world system, we
>   strongly suggest he make more restrictions than we indicate in the
>   rules. This may be particularly appropriate for spells of on the same
>   list (e.g. the Cleric Base list, Protections).

So in Rolemaster we can't "normally" combine the effects of spells of the same name, and **Bless** is pretty much the same name as **Bless**.

Therefore (and as I have always ruled in my *coughcoughcough* years of running Rolemaster and MERP) if a spell with a duration is cast once again then duration is extended (subject to successful RR and casting) unless there is clarification in the spell or by the GM to state otherwise.

**TLDR:** In MERP and Rolemaster recasting the spell extends the spells duration, it doesn't double it's effect.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of multiple castings in MERP is not really described clearly. To avoid issues with that, I usually set some house rules for this specific case. One way I found works well is the possibility for the caster to use more PP for extending spells, but with some additional chances of failure, something like:

- Casting the spell using the normal PP cost result in normal behaviour
- Using 2x the PP cost doubles the duration, 3x triples etc.
- Using 3x the cost doubles the effect, but the chance of failure increases by 5% for every PP higher than your level

In your case (2nd LVL Ranger with 2 PP) casting Bless (2nd LVL) you can:

- cast as normal using 2 PP or 1 Adder charge
- cast double duration with 2 PP plus 1 charge, or triple duration with 2 PP plus 2 charges
- cast double effect using up 2 PP plus 2 charges, but increase difficulty by (6 PP equivalent - 2 LVL ranger) = 4 * 5% = 20%

Comment: I have a ton of respect for you for giving such a detailed answer to a two year old question.